# Optimal CLion VM memory settings for very large projects

Tags: memory, jvm, settings, clion, large-data

Im currently working on a fork of a VERY LARGE project with about 7-8 * 10^6 LoC and 100000+ classes. The problem is, of course, that the indexer or CLion in general runs out of memory or is very slow and not responsive.

I already saw the blog entry https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/04/configuring-intellij-idea-vm-options/ where you describe some memory projects but it seems not to fit for my project setup.

My .vmoptions file looks like this:

```
-Xss20m
-Xms2560m
-Xmx20000m
-XX:NewSize=1280m
-XX:MaxNewSize=1280m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=500
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
-Dsun.java2d.renderer=sun.java2d.marlin.MarlinRenderingEngine
```

Im working on a machine with 128GB MainMemory and Intel XEON 28 Core CPU, so the resources should not be the problem.

Do you have any recommendations for the optimal memory settings?

Comment: Did you end up finding an optimal configuration that makes code navigation faster on your box? Does increasing the memory help with anything? Memory indicator for my current project never goes past 600MB, so I'm wondering if any of the code cache settings would help here instead.

Comment: unfortunately not but I stopped working on the project and haven't tried lately. It should work faster though since they fixed the issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3370)! If you really need better performance try Visual Studio Code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a mail to JetBrains support and this was the answer:

> The possibility to change how many cores should be used in CLion
>   hasn't been implemented yet, we have a related feature request:
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3370. Please comment or
>   upvote. Could you please capture a CPU snapshot so we can take a look
>   at what is going on?

So it would be great if anybody who wants this feature +1's it on JetBrains YouTrack.